# Setting a value for an input per jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am a bit puzzled by this behaviour.

I clone a table with jquery, then do a GET request to the server and get a json. From that I set the value for each field in the cloned table.

[image]

It all appears just fine on the screen, however I don't see any value in FireBug for that element.

```
<input id="id_deals-1-deal_template_name" type="text" maxlength="100" name="deals-1-deal_template_name" readonly="True">
```

The way I set the value is like this, maybe I do this wrong:

```
$('#id_deals-' + (total-1) + '-deal_template_name').val(template_name);
```

Comment: You're doing it right. A firebug refresh doesn't show you the attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` attribute sets the **default value**.

The `value` property, which is set by the jQuery `val()`, method deals with the **current value**.

You shouldn't see a change in the attribute when viewing in Firebug as you aren't changing the default value.

If you really want to change that then use `.attr('value', foo)` instead.